# set fan speed on ubuntu 16.04 laptop hp elitebook 2540p

Tags: overheating, fan, temperature, fancontrol, lm-sensors

my laptop has some issue with the fan it does not work properly, on windows i used hwinfo 32 to control it manually and set its speeed but it seems impossible on ubuntu. I have been searching for almost more then a month now. i am already using a cool pad but it does not help much. i have already checked other question to set speed using fancontrol, lm-sensors. but pwmconfig doest not work. i have the same issue as [fan control on HP Elitebook](https://askubuntu.com/questions/889221/fan-control-on-hp-elitebook) . can anybody help ?

Answer (score 0):

the only topic i seen is this one , let us know if it worked to help others  https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2121339

Comment: This is a [questions and answers site](https://askubuntu.com/about), not a link collection. Please include relevant content in your answer, not just a link to where the content may be. The link is nice to have in addition for reference or for further information. For more tips, see [How to answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/how-to-answer).

Comment: if i would have more info i would have add it, but i dont, and even though this info might be useful so i post it